# Problem with math superscript and subscript in arabxetex

Tags: math-mode, xetex, subscripts, superscripts, arabic

I would like use math superscript `^` instead of `\sp` in mathematical formulae in an Arabic environment when using [`arabxetex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/arabxetex). Unfortunately it doesn't work, see the below example. Is there a way to solve this problem? Similarly for `_` and `\sb`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}

\begin{document}

$a^2$ 
$a\sp{2}$
$a\sb{2}$

\begin{farsi}
$a^2$
$a\sp{2}$
$a\sb{2}$
\end{farsi}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See section 3.2.1 of the manual:

> **3.2.1 Contextual analysis of hamza**
>   As with ArabTeX, a contextual analysis of the input encoding is performed (at the font-mapping level) to automatically determine the carrier of the hamza, as illustrated by the following examples:
>
> ```
> \begin{arab}
> 'amruN, 'ibiluN, 'u_htuN, '"u_ht"uN, '"Uql"Id"Is, ra'suN, 'ar'asu,
> sa'ala, qara'a, bu'suN, 'ab'usuN, ra'ufa, ru'asA'u, bi'ruN, 'as'ilaTuN,
> ka'iba, qA'imuN, ri'AsaTuN, su'ila, samA'uN, barI'uN, sU'uN, bad'uN,
> ^say'uN, ^say'iN, ^say'aN, sA'ala, mas'alaTuN, saw'aTuN, _ha.tI'aTuN,
> ...
> ```

So `^` and `_` lose their meaning for math mode in the `arab`, `farsi` or `urdu` environments.

You can make `^` and `_` math active; their behavior will be the desired one in transliterated text, returning to the usual one in math mode. The code

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`^ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sp
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`^=\string"8000 \mathcode`_=\string"8000 }
```

is what you need. Here's a complete example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`^ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sp
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`^=\string"8000 \mathcode`_=\string"8000 }

\begin{document}

\begin{farsi}
\relax ^say'uN _ha.tI'aTuN

$a^2$
$a\sp{2}$
$a\sb{2}$
\end{farsi}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\relax` is needed if `^` or `_` are the first characters.

A better implementation, which fixes some problems with control sequence in math mode is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabxetex}

% define ^ and _ to do the right thing in math mode
\begingroup\lccode`~=`^ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sp
\begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\sb
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`^=\string"8000 \mathcode`_=\string"8000 }
\makeatletter
% redefine the codes used in the environments for Arab script
\def\arabtex@codes{%
  \catcode`^=12 \lccode`^=`^
  \catcode`_=12 \lccode`_=`_
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{farsi}
\relax ^say'uN _ha.tI'aTuN

$a^2$ $\tau_2$
$a\sp{2}$
$a\sb{2}$
\end{farsi}

\end{document}
```

You should make the maintainers aware of this better definition of `\arabtex@codes`. Characters with category code 11 or 12 are equivalent when hyphenation is concerned, so long as their `\lccode` is non zero.

Comment: Is it possible to modify you code in order to be compatible with math Greek letters? in fact writing something like $\tau_2$ in the environment \begin{farsi} \end{farsi}  produce the error `ERROR: Undefined control sequence'. On the other hand writing ${\tau}_2$ seems to correctly work.

Comment: @Name I don't know why `arabxetex` makes `_` and `^` into letters; I would have made them into “other characters”, but perhaps the authors have their reasons. You have to type `\tau _{2}` (the braces are optional but recommended). And maybe file a bug report.

Comment: strangely {\tau}_2 works but not \tau_{2}.

Comment: @Name I've added a better workaround.

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your great contributions.